# Package group names used in kickstart config on CentOS 7 cannot be found in CentOS 8

Tags: centos, kickstart

I am converting a CentOS 7 kickstart file to work with CentOS 8. In CentOS 7, the `%packages` section had these entries:

```
%packages
@^minimal
@core
kexec-tools
```

EDIT: I'm using `cdrom` as source for installation.
However, CentOS 8 does not like these entries and throws an error when the kickstart file is processed during installation:

```
missing groups or modules: @minimal, @core
```

Are there any corresponding groups names in CentOS 8 for these package groups? I looked through `BaseOS/repodata` of my `CentOS-8.2.2004-x86_64-minimal.iso` image and didn't find any of these names listed in the xml files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the output of `dnf group list -v`.  You might be able to get away with `minimal-environment`, which includes the `Core` group.

```
# dnf group info minimal-environment
Last metadata expiration check: 0:03:02 ago on Wed 16 Sep 2020 09:47:02 AM EDT.
Environment Group: Minimal Install
 Description: Basic functionality.
 Mandatory Groups:
   Core
 Optional Groups:
   Guest Agents
   Standard
```

I'd also suggest look at the output of `dnf group info Core` (and maybe also Standard), which is probably too long to include in this answer.

Changes between CentOS7 and CentOS8 made it so the old yum groups don't really line up with the DNF groups, so you'll need to update your kickstart appropriately.