# Kickstart: get sw installation list of minimal-centos8

Tags: centos, kickstart

I am trying to create a custom kickstart-file for our installation media, which will be based on a minimal centos8 installation. But to have a bit better knowledge about what is actually being installed during the minimal i actually did this installation manually to extract that kickstart file.

but when investigating the file i only see this in the "packages" part of the file:

```
%packages
@^minimal-environment
kexec-tools
%end
```

Searched the net, trying to find out what is actually being installed, but cannot find anything.
There is still 373 rpm-packages installed but i would like to have them in a kickstart-format.

Any ideas that could help me?

Thanks!

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/609595/package-group-names-used-in-kickstart-config-on-centos-7-cannot-be-found-in-cent

Answer (score 1):

**To see all groups you can use:**

> dnf group list -v

**For group information use this
Example:**

> dnf group info minimal-environment

#### About Environments, Groups, stream profiles and individual packages:

#### Specifying an environment (@^)

> Specify an entire environment to be installed as a line starting with the @^ symbols.

#### Specifying groups (@)

> Specify groups, one entry to a line, starting with an @ symbol, and then the full group name or group id as given in the *-comps-repository.architecture.xml file.

#### Specifying profiles of module streams (@module:stream/)

> Specify profiles for module streams, one entry to a line, using the syntax for profiles

#### Specifying individual packages (*)

> Specify individual packages by name, one entry to a line. You can use the asterisk character (*) as a wildcard in package names.

**For more Information:** https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html-single/performing_an_advanced_rhel_8_installation/index

**Section:**

- A.2.1. Package selection section
- A.2.2. Package selection commands